# How to run below command from vbscript

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have written vbscript code to set classpath of putty from command prompt

```
Dim oShell

putty_path="setx path %path%;C:\putty"
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K" & putty_path
Set oShell = Nothing
```

When i execute vbscript code i am getting below error in command prompt

ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has already worked, so it can't do it a second or subsequent time as it worked the first time. Just ignore.

Plus it's unnecessary what you are doing, just shell to PuTTY (you don't even need to use the extension).

```
oShell.run "putty"
```

Comment: Thank for the information how to run below command in oshell echo n | psftp.exe username@10.201.210.123 -pw 12322 -b C:\Scanner\act_image_server_local.scr  > c:\copy_act_image_server_local.txt

Comment: Redirection is handled by cmd.exe. So therefore you have to run it with cmd (a console window that you are creating doesn't have CMD running). Something like `oshell.run "cmd /c echo n | psftp.exe username@10.201.210.123 -pw 12322 -b C:\Scanner\act_image_server_local.scr > c:\copy_act_image_server_local.txt`